# AS3 Dynamically reference embedded graphics?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, loading

First off, I'm rather n00b at AS3 so I'm sorry if this is a terrible question. I've searched and can't find direct reference/solution to this exact issue.

**My Problem:**
I'm trying to embed all my pertinent graphics within a class("Assets.as") which will have a static method to retrieve these embedded graphics by name.

**What I've Tried:**

Assets.as

```
package
{
    [...imports...]

    public class Assets
    {       
        [Embed(source="assets/images/l_peak.png")]
        public static const l_peak:Class;

        public static function getByName(pName:String):Bitmap
        {
            var retClass:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(pName) as Class;
            return new Bitmap(new retClass());  
        }
    }
}
```

This however returns a null object. Any way I work this, the `getDefinitionByName()` either returns null or says there isn't an object named that(i.e. "l_peak").

I know you can use a loader() to do this dynamically with graphics, but I was hoping to embed these graphics and simply get them dynamically by their name.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't think you need the bitmap conversion. try return this[pName];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try:

```
return Assets[pName];
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for... For some reason I couldn't find a reference to it, or I overlooked one that I did.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the property has to be a public var not const but I could be wrong.
As a test try just public var

```
[Embed(source="assets/images/l_peak.png")]
public var l_peak:Class;
```

Additionally this article may help you out:
http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853

If you still have a problem it could be an issue with the path to your asset. From [live docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html):

> Specifies the name and path of the asset to embed; either an absolute path or a path relative to the file containing the embed statement. The embedded asset must be a locally stored asset. Therefore you cannot specify a URL for an asset to embed.
>   For more information on setting the path, see About setting the path to the embedded asset.

Comment: Still says "l_peak" is not defined? Odd.

Comment: check to make sure the path to your assets are correct. I believe the path is relative to the location of the AS file you are editing. I've edited my answer to include this option

Comment: The path is fine, I can initialize it via (new l_peak()) if i like.

Comment: What is the output if you do trace(getQualifiedClassName(new l_peak()))? Whatever get's traced out there is the string you should be passing into getDefinitionByName()

Comment: Eduardo's solution was more what I was looking for, but I'll +1 as your solution would work as well.